# Why do I get these differences on ppa vs. snap Communitheme in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, themes, ppa, snap

I installed Communitheme time ago by the PPA using these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:communitheme/ppa**
sudo apt install ubuntu-communitheme-session**
```

Everything worked fine. I just had to log in Ubuntu Communitheme and  I had my Ubuntu icon as the menu icon on the Dock.

Ubuntu menu icon in the Dock:

[image: Ubuntu menu icon in the dock]

I just had the Communitheme option on apps on the gnome tweak-tool, not on icons or mouse, so I decided to see what was happening at `/usr/share/icons/communitheme` and this is what I found.

No Ubuntu icon for Communitheme:

[image: No icon folder for communitheme]

I did not give importance because I am using other icons and mouse but didn't get why it was happening. The thing is this morning when I logged in and updated system my environment skin changed.

Dock skin changed:

[image: Dock skin changed]

And then I discovered that there is a snap package of the Communitheme, so I decided to install it. To my surprise when I logged out and tried to log in again there were new options and if I log in Ubuntu snap communitheme everything is normal again and I also discovered that I have icon folder.

Communitheme icon folder:

[image: Communitheme icon folder]

Why is this happening? Should it not be the same installing from a snap or from a PPA?

Now it doesn't matter which session I log in, the Ubuntu dock looks like in the screenshot (Dock skin changed), tried to remove all PPA packages but keeps being the same,and decided to install again the PPA packages because I realized that there are different things with different skins if I just maintain the snap version. If anyone knows about this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The ppa has been deprecated and doesn't reliably build anymore new versions.

Only the snap is the supported documented way and you should remove/purge the ppa and packages that are installed into it to ensure you get the tested and supported stack.